# ASP.NET Core Web API - Route Constraints for Lists/Arrays

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API action that should receive a list of guids.

Now I'm trying to add the correct constraint to the route but I can't find an example for lists.

Right now my Action looks like this but this is the constraint for a single value.

```
[HttpGet("Info/{guids:guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid[] guids)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Is it possible to add this constraint or is there no constraint for this available right now?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is one according to their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints)

Comment: You can implement yours though. Check this blog post by Scott to get you started: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingACustomInlineRouteConstraintInASPNETCore10.aspx

Comment: Have you considered to use [FromQuery] to get the guid from query strings like `Info?guids=xxx&guids=xxx`.Your action needs `[FromQuery(Name = "guids")] List<Guid> guids`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 options for you.

One option would be to use regex.
`[HttpGet("Info/{guids:regex((([{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?)[\,]?)+)}")]` 
but this is not pretty at all and difficult to read (my regex also needs a re-look, made it just to make the point).

A more cleaner way is to implement a custom constraint.

```
   public class GuidListConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var valueActuallySubmitted = values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var value);

        if (!valueActuallySubmitted) return false;

        var guidListAsString = value.ToString();
        var splitOnComma = guidListAsString.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var guidValue in splitOnComma)
        {
            var isProperGuid = Guid.TryParse(guidValue, out var _);
            if (!isProperGuid) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Which you can register after `services.AddMvc()` as

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.ConstraintMap.Add("myguidlist", typeof(GuidListConstraint)));
```

Then you can decorate your actions like 
`[HttpGet("Info/{guids:myguidlist}")]`

Haven't thoroughly tested this but with a little customisation it should give you a good headstart.